# How can I write once the crosstab function to yield more than one table and the percentage column

Tags: python, pivot-table

look a the following code, II need to write a single line code instead of all his, Do any suggestions far

```
idx = g[['Gender', 'MaritalStatus']]
col = g['Group']
getallcrosstabonce = pd.crosstab(index=idx, columns=col)
```

output should be:

tabla1

```
       Group1| group2 | percent
Male  | 12   | 43     | 10%
Female| 23   | 12     |  4%

table2 marital status...
........
table3....
```